# How to do this using lodash?

Tags: lodash

I have array of objects e.g

```
    [ { fName: 'Sohail',
    lName: 'Afzal',
    dob: 1995-07-08T19:00:00.000Z,
    gender: 'Male',
    phone: '(612)545-8924',
    phone1: '(123)456-7890',
    payorName: 'hashir',
    payorId: 12,
    affiliationDate: 2018-10-09T19:00:00.000Z },
  { fName: 'Joann',
    mName: 'Denise',
    lName: 'Gasner',
    dob: 1964-10-13T19:00:00.000Z,
    gender: 'Male',
    phone: '(612)990-8450',
    phone1: '(612)545-8924',
    payorName: 'Nouman Latif',
    payorId: 15,
    affiliationDate: 2018-10-10T19:00:00.000Z } ]
```

fetch some data from object and store in array then again push data into object. I need to group last three element into single array name payInfo

Output want like

```
[ { fName: 'Sohail',
        lName: 'Afzal',
        dob: 1995-07-08T19:00:00.000Z,
        gender: 'Male',
        phone: '(612)545-8924',
        phone1: '(123)456-7890',
        payInfo:[{payorName: 'hashir',
        payorId: 12,
        affiliationDate: 2018-10-09T19:00:00.000Z}]
       },
      { fName: 'Joann',
        mName: 'Denise',
        lName: 'Gasner',
        dob: 1964-10-13T19:00:00.000Z,
        gender: 'Male',
        phone: '(612)990-8450',
        phone1: '(612)545-8924',
        payInfo:[{payorName: 'Nouman Latif',
        payorId: 15,
        affiliationDate: 2018-10-10T19:00:00.000Z}] 
         } ]
```

Need to solve this with lodash.

Comment: You data is confusing. What key/prop connects the payer? In one it has `12` in the other you have 2 `15`

Comment: Yes i update the code. Basically i need to group last three element of object in single array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const data = [{ fName: 'Sohail', lName: 'Afzal', dob: '1995-07-08T19:00:00.000Z', gender: 'Male', phone: '(612)545-8924', phone1: '(123)456-7890', payorName: 'hashir', payorId: 15, affiliationDate: '2018-10-09T19:00:00.000Z' }, { fName: 'Joann', mName: 'Denise', lName: 'Gasner', dob: '1964-10-13T19:00:00.000Z', gender: 'Male', phone: '(612)990-8450', phone1: '(612)545-8924', payorName: 'Nouman Latif', payorId: 15, affiliationDate: '2018-10-10T19:00:00.000Z' } ]

const result = _.map(data, x => 
   _.omit(_.extend(x, { payInfo: [{ 
      payorName: x.payorName, 
      payorId: x.payorId, 
      affiliationDate: x.affiliationDate 
   }] 
}), ['payorName', 'payorId', 'affiliationDate']))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using the `_.extend` to decorate the object and `_.omit` to remove the old fields.

With **ES6** you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const data = [{ fName: 'Sohail', lName: 'Afzal', dob: '1995-07-08T19:00:00.000Z', gender: 'Male', phone: '(612)545-8924', phone1: '(123)456-7890', payorName: 'hashir', payorId: 15, affiliationDate: '2018-10-09T19:00:00.000Z' }, { fName: 'Joann', mName: 'Denise', lName: 'Gasner', dob: '1964-10-13T19:00:00.000Z', gender: 'Male', phone: '(612)990-8450', phone1: '(612)545-8924', payorName: 'Nouman Latif', payorId: 15, affiliationDate: '2018-10-10T19:00:00.000Z' } ]

const result = data.map(({payorName, payorId, affiliationDate, ...x}) => {
   x.payInfo = [{ payorName, payorId, affiliationDate }]
   return x
})

console.log(result)
```

Or even more concise via `Object.assign`:

```js
const data = [{ fName: 'Sohail', lName: 'Afzal', dob: '1995-07-08T19:00:00.000Z', gender: 'Male', phone: '(612)545-8924', phone1: '(123)456-7890', payorName: 'hashir', payorId: 15, affiliationDate: '2018-10-09T19:00:00.000Z' }, { fName: 'Joann', mName: 'Denise', lName: 'Gasner', dob: '1964-10-13T19:00:00.000Z', gender: 'Male', phone: '(612)990-8450', phone1: '(612)545-8924', payorName: 'Nouman Latif', payorId: 15, affiliationDate: '2018-10-10T19:00:00.000Z' } ]

const result = data.map(({payorName, payorId, affiliationDate, ...x}) => 
  Object.assign(x, {payInfo: [{ payorName, payorId, affiliationDate }]}))

console.log(result)
```